# send data back to the application

Tags: extjs

I'm very new to EXTJS, so I dont fully understand how does it work yet, but I manage to build a grid that is a result of a select (so it is not mapped directly to a table). One of the columns of this grid is ID. I also added a checkbox to the grid

```
    this.columns =
    [
        {
            header: 'Selected',
            dataIndex: 'Selected',
            xtype: 'checkcolumn'
        },
        ....rest of the columns
```

and on my model I have:

```
fields:
[   
    { name: 'Selected', type: 'bool' },
    { name: 'ID', type: 'int' },
     ...rest of the fields
```

what I need is, on the click of a button (which is already added), to get a list of the IDs that had the Selected property set to true.

Any Idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that is simple (if I understand you right), a grid has a [selection model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getSelectionModel) which handles these selection. You will just need to get the selection model and get all [selected](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelection) records.

There are also [itemclick](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick),[selectionchange](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-selectionchange) events that fires for each selection. Where the second gives a array of selected records.

And I guess the [Ext.selection.CheckboxModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel) can be also interest you.

**Edit:**

OK I guess all above is not what you want but maybe quite interesting. What you need is to iterate over all records of the store which can be done with [store.each()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each). Do this in the scope of your button and will a array. Example

```
var myGrid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid');
var list = [];
myGrid.store.each(function(rec) { 
    if(rec.data.Selected)
        list.push(rec);
    return true;
});
```

To get the currently selected record(model) do this:

```
var myGrid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid'),
    sm = myGrid.getSelectionModel(),
    selection = sm.getSelection(), // gives you a array of records(models)
    len = selection.length, 
    i = 0, 
    idList = []; 

for (; i<len; i++) { 
   idList.push(selection[i].data.ID); 
}
```

Comment: what is store? I thought it was the grid, so I got it using: var myGrid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid'); but when I tried to apply the method each I got: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'each'

Comment: Well normally a grid is bound to a store which has your model applied. The store handles all the communication with your server while the grid only renders what's in the store. To apply the method each you should use `var myGrid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid'); myGrid.store.each(...`

Comment: cool, the error whent away. One more question, where in that code do you mention the Selected column (the one with the checkbox) and the ID column (the integer I want returned)? Thanks

Comment: @Diego this is the important part! Based on your model and my understanding the selected property is a boolean value that get set by the server and can occur multiple times. The example functions returns a list of records(models) where selected is true. But if you want to get the currently selected record within the grid you have to (and should) use the selectionmodel of the grid. Edit of my post will follow

Comment: no no I need all array, whant I'm not understanding is where in the code are yoy saying that the selected column is called "Selected" and that the property I want returned is the "ID"